# bootstrap multiselect search issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have implemented bootstrap multiselect with search in my project but when I search something which is present in drop down then its showing "Select All" but I want to show no item found.

below is my implementation of bootstrap:

```
$('.multiselectFilter').multiselectFilters({
    enableFiltering: true,
    filterPlaceholder: 'Search',
    enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering : true,
    includeSelectAllOption: true,
    filterPlaceholder: 'Search',
    dropRight: true
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to set this attribute to false

```
includeSelectAllOption: false
```

then it wouldnt ask you to `select all` the values

Comment: @user2696466: what exactly are you expecting ? the multiselect filter should shows the values which  searched for without asking you to select all options right ?

Answer (score 1):

try with onChange

```
$('.multiselectFilter').multiselectFilters({
    enableFiltering: true,
    filterPlaceholder: 'Search',
    enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering : true,
    includeSelectAllOption: true,
    filterPlaceholder: 'Search',
    dropRight: true,
    onChange: function (elem, chk) {
      //your message
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

By enabling CaseInsensitive filtering true makes more desired results e.g.

enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true